# Show that $ \frac{1}{e}=1-1+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}+... $.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

This question is from Courant Calculus/Analysis book Vol 1, Section 1.7 Question 7:

> Show that $ \frac{1}{e}=1-1+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}+... $.  Hint:  Consider the product of the nth partial sums of the expansions for e and 1/e.

It seems that after doing partial sums for $e$ and the supposed $1/e$ we should have $1+c$ for some error value $c$.  Then we take limits to infinity and $c$ should be $0$. I find the products of those sums too confusing and don't know how to get $1+c$.

Comment: What you've attempted?

Comment: At Vol 1, Section 1.7  we still (don't) know that $e^x= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n!}$ I suppose...

Comment: @Raffaele no, is that easily proven without calculus?

Comment: Of course not! Just cheating a bit... :)  It requires Taylor's series expansion

Comment: @Raffaele That depends. In some books, they use your series to define the function $e^x$, and then say that the number $e$ is just the value of this function at $x = 1$. Which direction one wants to go is a matter of taste, though.

Answer (score 5):

Define $e_n = \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac1{i!}$ and $f_n = \sum_{j = 0}^n\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}$. The hope is that $\lim_{n\to \infty} e_nf_n = 1$. Is that what really happens?
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}e_nf_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac1{i!}\right)\left(\sum_{j = 0}^n\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\right)\\
= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i = 0}^n \left(\frac1{i!}\cdot \sum_{j = 0}^n\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\right)\\
= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i, j = 0}^n\frac{(-1)^j}{i!\cdot j!}
$$
At this point, I wish to split the sum up into two parts: One part for when $i+j \leq n$, and one for $i+j > n$. I'll handle the second part first.

There are $n(n+1)/2$ terms in this second part. The largest term (in absolute value) is strictly smaller than $\frac{1}{(n/2)!^2}$ (if you'll excuse my use of factorial on something which is possibly not an integer). The exact size is
$$
\text{Largest term in the second part } = \cases{\dfrac{1}{\frac{n}{2}!\cdot \frac{n+2}{2}!} & if $n$ is even\\ \dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}!\right)^2}& if $n$ is odd}
$$
and can be used in the argument to below, but for typographical and reading simplicity I'll leave the slightly invalid (because of non-integers) approximation in place. The sum of all of the terms in the second part is therefore less than 
$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{(n/2)!^2}
$$
which we can see goes toward $0$ as $n$ increases, for instance by noting that $n(n+1)< 2\cdot 3 \cdot \frac n2\cdot \frac n2$, and what's left in the denominator is at least $\frac n2 - 1$.

So we're left with the first part. That is,
$$
\sum_{i+j \leq n\\i, j\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^j}{i!j!}
$$
Let's take this one diagonal at a time. In other words, decompose this sum into
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^n\sum_{i + j = k\\i, j \geq 0}\frac{(-1)^j}{i!j!}
$$
Here we can see that the inner sum is $1/k!$ times the binomial expansion of $(1 - 1)^k$ (at least for $k > 0$; I won't get into $0^0$ discussions here). So the sum of the first part is exactly equal to $1$.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: What is meant by 'inner sum'?  can you explain that last sentence more in depth?

Comment: @helios321 What I mean is that for any $k\in \Bbb N$, the binomial theorem tells us (with some minor rearranging) that
$$
\sum_{i + j = k\\i, j \geq 0}\frac{(-1)^j}{i!j!} = (1-1)^k/k!
$$I call it the "inner" sum because it's the one that's on the "inside", while $\sum_{k = 0}^n$ is on the "outside". The "outside" (entire) sum then becomes $1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 = 1$, where each of those terms corresponds to one choice of $k$.

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious how you get the largest terms for when $i+j>n$.  Whats the short explanation?

Comment: @helios321 The largest term must have $i+j = n+1$, since otherwise you can just decrease either $i$ or $j$ by $1$, and get a larger term still counted in the second part. Next, if $i$ and $j$ are not as close together as possible, then increasing the smallest of them by $1$ while decreasing the largest of them by $1$ will give a larger term. Therefore the largest term is when $i+j = n+1$ and at the same time $i$ and $j$ are as close to one another as possible in value.

Comment: We can also use this method to show that $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n/n!)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x)^n/n!)=1$ for every complex $x.$